# gpo grant user permissions to install any software from a partner

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I my work environment, when user want to install new software, he has to send to software to security officer to get approval. Some coming from well know partner don't really need to be approved, but they still go through the same process. This is waist of time and money for users and security officer. I was wandering if there is a way to do this through active directory. Basically to set a rule that allow user to install any software coming from our partner without going through security officer.

Normally software from our partners are signed so it is theoretically possible. But I don't know if this is possible with a GPO.

Thank in advance.

dmx.

Comment: No Active Directory does not provide that functionality. That would need to be a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up applocker or software restriction policies at the client, you may limit what he can run to software signed by certain software publishers using certificates. Still, the person installing it would need administrative permissions and a local admin may circumvent all GPOs, so it's no real protection.